# Can't make foundation sections example work

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm new to foundation and I'm trying to make some nice tabs with various content. To do so, I'm using [their documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/section.html). However, it doesn't work like it's supposed to do.
Averything works fine, except that that sections don't cover each other. Each section is placed after the other, even when the other is hidden. Here is an example :

1. [image: First tab]
2. [image: Some other tab]

As you can see, this is pretty ugly. Here is my code :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Test Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/autoPA/static/css/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/autoPA/static/css/foundation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/autoPA/static/css/dynamease.css" />

<script src="/autoPA/static/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="section-container auto" data-section>
        <section>
            <p class="title" data-section-title>
                <a href="#panel1">Section 1</a>
            </p>
            <div class="content" data-section-content>
                <p>Content of section 1.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <p class="title" data-section-title>
                <a href="#panel2">Section 2</a>
            </p>
            <div class="content" data-section-content>
                <p>Content of section 2.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <!-- Check for Zepto support, load jQuery if necessary -->
    <script>
        document
                .write('<script src='
                        + ('__proto__' in {} ? '/autoPA/static/js/vendor/zepto'
                                : '/autoPA/static/js/vendor/jquery')
                        + '.js><\/script>')
    </script>
    <script src="/autoPA/static/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).foundation();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Do you guys see anything wrong in it ? (Each file included is found, firebug doesn't detect any errors).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
<script src="/autoPA/static/js/lib/foundation/foundation.section.js"></script>
```

...to the bottom of your page.

BTW, I can't get mine to work either :-/

UPDATE: foundation.min.js already contains foundation.section.js My bad!

Comment: No problems. I asked the same question on the google group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/foundation-framework-/u320Ty6PKTA), I'll let you know if I can make it work.